# Need some help understanding this exercise about injective plane curve

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition

Let $\gamma (t) = (x(t), y(t))$ be a smooth regular plane curve $\gamma: I \to \mathbb R^2$ where $I$ is some open interval.

Now consider the following exercise:

Let $\varphi (u,v) = (x(u), v + y(u))$. Show that $\varphi $ is injective if and only if $x$ is. With $\gamma (t) = (t^3, t)$ show that $\varphi$ is bijective but $\varphi^{-1}$ is not smooth at points where $x=0$.

Show that for any $\gamma$, $\varphi$ is a local diffeomorphism at $(u_0,v_0)$ provided $x'(u_0)\neq 0$, that is, provided the tangent to the curve at $t=u_0$ is not *vertical*. If $x'(u_0)=0$ then $y(u_0)\neq 0$ (why?). In that case redefine $\varphi$ to be $\varphi (u,v)$ to be $(v + x(u), y(u))$: this is a local diffeomorphism at $(u_0,v_0)$.

> My question is not about the solution, I think I can do that, but
>   rather about the insight I should gain here. For example, why would I
>   define such a map $\varphi$?

For example, $\gamma$ is a local diffeo iff $x'(t)\neq 0$ so saying the same about $\varphi$ does not seem to yield any new insight!

Comment: Why do you say $\gamma$ is a diffeomorphism? It's not even a homeomorphism (for one thing, the dimensions of the domain and range don't match.)

Comment: to say the velocity of the path is nonzero is to say the path is regular. So, this problem is about how regularity allows you to build surfaces by simple formula. The formulas for $\phi(u,v)$ basically follow the path by $u$ then use $v$ to trace out a band either in the $x$ or $y$ direction.  Geometrically, it's like a ribbon.

Comment: Oh, I see your curve is just in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Perhaps ribbon is the wrong term, it's like taking a thick marker and either broadening the curve horizontally or vertically. If you had a path just stop at a point, then the marker strip I describe would abruptly end and I believe that would cause the mapping $\phi$ to fail to be locally invertible.

Comment: @user7530 I didn't say diffeomorphism, I said local diffeomorphism :-)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Oh, thank you very much. I see, we are constructing surfaces from curves! (Actually, wouldn't it be nicer to scale by multiplication $\varphi(x(u), vy(u)$?) If then $\varphi$ is injective (bijective) do we call the surface immersed?

Comment: I'd say it's nicer to instead draw rulings along the normal direction (or in 3D, along one basis vector of a moving frame). This way you can get things like e.g. developable surfaces by choosing the Bishop frame.

Comment: @user7530 agreed. The construction here is pretty adhoc, although, easy to set-up, so I see why it's done.